# how to merge tag having same same in wordpress ethier by plugin or raw php code by single shot

Tags: php, wordpress

i have tried raw php code for the merging tags but it could not handle the load as there are 500 000 data results. i have tried plugin term management tool but we have manually merge tags. there is so much data.

```
<p>
<?php
    
    require_once('wp-load.php');
   

    global $wpdb;    
            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT uv_terms.slug,uv_terms.term_id,uv_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id,uv_term_taxonomy.count FROM uv_terms INNER JOIN uv_term_taxonomy ON uv_term_taxonomy.term_id=uv_terms.term_id  WHERE taxonomy='post_tag' ORDER BY uv_terms.slug DESC  LIMIT 30000");
            $totalCount=0;
            $noOfSlug=0;
            $captainTax=[]; 
            $countPerTax=[];
            $duplicateTax=[];
            $slug=[];
            $captainTerm=[];
            $duplicateTerm=[];

            foreach ($result  as $res) {
                if($totalCount==0){
                    $captainTax[$noOfSlug]=$res->term_taxonomy_id;
                    $duplicateTax[$noOfSlug]=$res->term_taxonomy_id;
                    $countPerTax[$noOfSlug]=$res->count;
                    $slug[$noOfSlug]=strtolower(preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','',trim($res->slug)));
                    $captainTerm[$noOfSlug]=$res->term_id;
                    $duplicateTerm[$noOfSlug]=$res->term_id;
                    $totalCount++;
                }else{
                    if(!strcmp($slug[$noOfSlug],strtolower(preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','',trim($res->slug))))){
                        $duplicateTax[$noOfSlug]=$duplicateTax[$noOfSlug].','.$res->term_taxonomy_id;
                        $countPerTax[$noOfSlug]=$countPerTax[$noOfSlug]+$res->count;
                        $duplicateTerm[$noOfSlug]=$duplicateTerm[$noOfSlug].','.$res->term_id;
                        $totalCount++;
                    }else{
                        $noOfSlug++;
                        $captainTax[$noOfSlug]=$res->term_taxonomy_id;
                        $duplicateTax[$noOfSlug]=$res->term_taxonomy_id;
                        $countPerTax[$noOfSlug]=$res->count;
                        $slug[$noOfSlug]=strtolower(preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','',trim($res->slug)));
                        $captainTerm[$noOfSlug]=$res->term_id;
                        $duplicateTerm[$noOfSlug]=$res->term_id;
                        $totalCount++;
                    }
                }
                
            }
            // echo "<br/>Captain taxonomy";
            // var_dump($captainTax);
            // echo "<br/>duplicate taxonomy";
            // var_dump($duplicateTax);
            // echo "<br/>Count per taxonomy";
            // var_dump($countPerTax);
            // echo "<br/>slug";
            // var_dump($slug);
            // echo "<br/>captain term";
            // var_dump($captainTerm);
            // echo "<br/>duplicate term";
            // var_dump($duplicateTerm);

            for($i=0;$i<count($captainTax);$i++){
            $dupTax=explode(",",$duplicateTax[$i]); 
            $dupTerm=explode(",",$duplicateTerm[$i]);
            $result_taxonomy = $wpdb->get_results("UPDATE uv_term_taxonomy SET uv_term_taxonomy.count=".$countPerTax[$i]." WHERE uv_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=".$captainTax[$i]);
                for($j=0;$j<count($dupTax);$j++){
                    $result_relationship = $wpdb->get_results("UPDATE uv_term_relationships SET uv_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=".$captainTax[$i]." WHERE uv_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=".(int)$dupTax[$j]);
                    if($j>0){
                         $result_tax_del=$wpdb->get_results("DELETE FROM uv_term_taxonomy WHERE uv_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=".(int)$dupTax[$j]);
                        $result_term_del=$wpdb->get_results("DELETE FROM uv_terms WHERE uv_terms.term_id=".(int)$dupTerm[$j]);

                    }
                }   
            }
?>
</p>
```

Comment: merrging same slug...

Comment: the image was broken